# Hyperledger composer-cli cannot uninstall, no such file or directory

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ubuntu-18.04, nvm

I have successfully connecting 2 machine with Hyperledger composer. Somehow in the middle, the couched crashed. So somehow I want to restart my Hyperledger from the start.
When I tried to create admin card, `No version of composer-cli has been detected, you need to install composer-cli at v0.19 or higher`

So I did a little bit search at stack overflow and found some good information. Then I tried to uninstall composer-cli and reinstall it.
when I tried to uninstall it, `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/ptech_root/package.json'`.

I don't know why this happens.
when I tried to install `npm install -g composer-cli@0.20`, I get this.

```
    /home/ptech_root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/bin/composer -> /home/ptech_root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ composer-cli@0.20.7
updated 1 package in 9.083s
```

but seems like I cannot uninstall it.
any idea why?
I think it is because of the PATH. But I don't know what should I do with this. I am fairly new in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem

I was using ubuntu at azure VM, I need to use `sh ./createPeerAdminCard.sh` instead of `./createPeerAdminCard.sh`. I am not sure why this works. In my amazon VM I don't need to put this SH, so if anyone know why this `sh` thing is  works at azure, but not at amazon, please share why.